# Monad - bind method

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, bind, monads

I dont understand why i get this "bmDup is not a function" error while the info tells me that I need to retrieve a Maybe.
If I wrap it in a function, it is return undefined.

```js
function Maybe () {
  Object.freeze(this);
};

function Just (x) {
  this.toString = function () { return "Just " + x.toString(); };
  this.just = x;
  Object.freeze(this);
};
Just.prototype = new Maybe();
Just.prototype.constructor = Just;

function Nothing () {
  this.toString = function () { return "Nothing"; };
  Object.freeze(this);
};
Nothing.prototype = new Maybe();
Nothing.prototype.constructor = Nothing;

Maybe.unit = function (x) {
  // return a Maybe that holds x
  return new Just (x);
};

Maybe.bind = function (f) {
  // given a function from a value to a Maybe return a function from a Maybe to a Maybe
  return new Maybe(f(this.just));
};

//to test
function mDup(str) {
  return new Just(str+str);
}
console.log(mDup("abc"));           // => new Just("abcabc") OK
var bmDup = Maybe.bind(mDup);
console.log(bmDup(new Just("abc"))) // => new Just("abcabc") NOK
```

Comment: You really should try strict mode, so that all these mistakes surface as exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

First, let's look at what `Maybe.bind` actually does.

```
Maybe.bind = function (f) {
  // Construct a new Maybe object, passing in the result of f(this.just)
  return new Maybe(f(this.just));
};
```

Okay, so what is a `Maybe` object?

```
function Maybe () {
  Object.freeze(this);
};
```

Well, it's a frozen object. So `Maybe.bind` returns an object, not a function.

Comment: The instructions say that i need to return a Maybe, which is not a function. So I dont understand what this means "given a function from a value to a Maybe return a function from a Maybe to a Maybe", do you?

Comment: @kalia You've got me. Every time I think I understand monads, I realize I really don't.